# HTML: Unordered List isn't ordered correctly

Tags: javascript, list, unordered

I've been going around in circles for the last three hours trying to fix this, it's very odd...

I have an unordered list which is dynamically generated like so:

```
var numberOfSlides = 7;

for (i = 0; i < numberOfSlides; i++) {

    main.menu.append("<li class='ui-state-disabled'>List item " + i + "</a></li>");

}
```

This correct renders (all disabled):

```
List item 0
List item 1
List item 2
List item 3
List item 4
List item 5
List item 6
```

Later in the code I call a function that should activate a specified item:

```
enableMenuItem(2);
```

---

```
enableMenuItem: function(slideNumber){

    console.log("slideNumber: " + slideNumber); // log outputs "slideNumber: 2"

    $("ul li").eq(slideNumber).removeClass('ui-state-disabled'); // this doesn't work

}
```

It works fine for other values, but not 2, and I've found that if I call enableMenuItem(5), 2 is then activated.

The weird thing is if I do this...

```
$("ul li").eq(2).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

...it works.

But this doesn't...

```
if(slideNumber === 2){
    console.log("slideNumber equals 2"); // logs "slideNumber equals 2", so the below line should execute
    $("ul li").eq(2).removeClass('ui-state-disabled'); // doesn't work
}
```

Am I going insane or is this very odd?

Comment: Have you tried `function enableMenuItem(slideNumber){...`

Comment: Maybe `main.menu.find("> li").eq(slideNumber)` ? I have no idea what `main.menu` is in your code, since it's not a variable ..

Comment: It would be great if you post a reproducible example in JSFiddle so we can test it on our browser.

Comment: I hadn't, but I just tried it with no luck. I think if that was the issue then no values would work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Kaloyan, main.menu.find("> li").eq(slideNumber) worked!

Thank you so much. I'm still curious as to why my method doesn't work though, especially as it's only one value that doesn't work.

Thanks again, much appreciated - I don't think I would have slept tonight if I didn't get that fixed.

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov, I'm new to stackoverflow, but I can see it works on a points system. Do you want to put your comment as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are appending the items to `main.menu` you should bind the events to the same thing.
Like so:

```
main.menu.find("> li").eq(slideNumber).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

If you have other unordered lists in the document `$("ul li")` will target them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your declaration of your `enableMenuItem` method:

```
enableMenuItem: function(slideNumber){
  // Some code
}
```

You should declare it as:

```
function enableMenuItem(slideNumber) {
  // Some code
}
```

or

```
var enableMenuItem = function(slideNumber) {
  // Some code
}
```

Comment: Hew avik, it's not a typo, I'm using using a pseudo namespace object. Thanks for your input though.